# What is exact dplyr behavior if user calls select() instead of filter() with a row-filter expression? (Gotcha)

Tags: r, select, filter, undefined-behavior, dplyr

dplyr silently lets it pass if a user mistakenly calls `select()` on a tbl_df with a row-filter expression, instead of `filter()`.

How exactly does `select()` evaluate a row-filter expression (should be meaningless), and why does it evaluate to always-TRUE?
Instead of FALSE, which would help catch the error (and/or raising warning 'Warning: select() received meaningless expression'), both of which would be better behavior?

```
require(dplyr)
set.seed(1234)
df <- tbl_df(data.frame(u=sample.int(3,10,replace=T), v=sample.int(4,10,replace=T)))

df %.% select(u!=3 & v>=3) # NONSENSE! silently passes all rows of df!

df %.% filter(u!=3 & v>=3) # CORRECT: filters only the 4 rows specified

u v
1 1 3
2 2 3
3 2 4
4 2 4    

u v
1  2 3
2  1 3
3  1 2
4  2 3
5  1 2
6  3 3
7  1 3
8  1 2
9  3 1
10 3 4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a look of the source [code](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/R/select-vars.R#L49).

To fully understand what is going on, let's do `debug(select_vars_q)` then run `df %.% select(u!=3 & v>=3)`.

The variables `vars` and `args` are

```
Browse[2]> vars
[1] "u" "v"
Browse[2]> args
[[1]]
u != 3 & v >= 3
```

Next, we only consider the lines which are related to `args`. For instance, in line [107](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/R/select-vars.R#L107)

```
debug: ind_list <- lapply(args, eval, env = select_env)
Browse[2]> lapply(args, eval, env = select_env)
[[1]]
[1] FALSE
```

This line is used when `args` is `starts_with`, `ends_with`,...etc. (see [67](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/R/select-vars.R#L67)), and it will return variable index number based on `args`.

In our case, the returned value is `FALSE` which is `0` (why? since [61](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/R/select-vars.R#L61) implies `u=1` and `v=2`), therefore, it does not match any variables, then this [line](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/R/select-vars.R#L112) will ensure all columns will be returned when nothing is matched.

---

To confirm my analysis, let's run this confusing command `df %.% select(u=2)`, 
According to above analysis, `ind_list` will be `2`, it means that column 2 will be returned. And the result:

```
> df %.% select(u=2)
Source: local data frame [10 x 1]

   u
1  3
2  3
3  2
4  4
5  2
6  4
7  2
8  2
9  1
10 1
```

Yes, it is the 2nd column.!

***In short, if the argument of select is not `starts_with`, `ends_with`...etc, and when the argument is a number (or can be evaluated as a number), then that number will be interpreted as column number.***

For example, `df %.% select(1)` returns the first column and `df %.% select(2)` returns the 2nd column.

Comment: Great analysis. Do you agree it sounds like a [useability bug/grounds for a warning](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues) to fail to parse a `select()` expression?

Comment: it is sensible to show warnings for such expressions, but it is hard to avoid all possible human error...for example, would you avoid `df %.% select(u=2)`? It may make sense for some cases (while doesn't in many other cases).

Comment: Yes I'm not talking about putting training wheels on everything, just catching easy-to-catch and common user error.

Comment: I don't know for others, but it is quite clear for me `select` applies to columns and `filter` applies to rows...may be because I know sql, and sql has similar keywords.

Comment: Randy, if you come from the R world with `plyr:ddply()`, or from any other programming language, it isn't though... look at e.g. how freely Python people mix the words 'select' and 'filter'. I do read all documentation religiously, but common mistakes still happen.

Comment: For example, look how freely Python [pandas documentation mixes the terms indexing, selecting and slicing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html)

Comment: It would be nice if `select()` could warn you when you're using it incorrectly, but I think it's very very hard due to the design of the function.